# Add event to Series.Toggle in Rickshaw

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, rickshaw

I want to add functionality when clicking on items in the legend in Rickshaw. I use the standard code to add toggle functionality, which I want to extend to run my own function:

```
shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle( { 
        graph: graph,
        legend: legend
}
```

Is there a way add a function of my own here? I also tried looking through and editing the code in Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle.js, but I couldn't get anything to run upon clicking items in the legend. (Might it be that the imported js file is cached so that my edits don't take effect?)

Answer (score 0):

As you explicitly asked about what source code to modify, I highlighted it below.
If you modify the source, upgrading to a new version becomes much harder, extending/creating own version would be the preferred way to go.

In [Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle.js](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle.js)
'Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle.js' change the following

```
Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle = function(args) {
  ...
  this._addBehavior = function() {
    this.graph.series.forEach( function(s) {
       s.disable = function() {
         if (self.graph.series.length <= 1) {
           throw('only one series left');
         }
         s.disabled = true;
         alert('disabling ' + s.name); //HERE
         self.graph.update();
       };

       s.enable = function() {
         s.disabled = false;
         alert('enabling ' + s.name); //HERE
         self.graph.update();
       };
    } );
  };
  ...
};
```